# XPath selection for repeating node structure in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while.

XML Example is:

```
<node>
  <ID>123</ID>
  <work>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Engineer</title>
    <description>
      <short>short</short>
    </description>
  </work>
  <work>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Engineer</title>
    <description>
      <short>long</short>
    </description>
  </work>
</node>
```

XSLT 2.0 Example:

```
<xsl:template name="answers">
    <xsl:for-each select="//description">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ancestor::node[ID='123']/work[2]/description/short"> 
                //DO NOTHING.
            </xsl:when>
            <otherwise>
                 <description>
                  //CREATE OTHERS
                 </description>
            </otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The idea here is to create new template to call "for-each description" part. But I want only the first description, because I will write the second one inside the first one. So I don't need to create anything for second description. Just ignore when it is the second description which has `<short>` node. The solution cannot be defined using the value `short='long'`. Because the language or the value can change but the XPath position will always be the same.

The result i am getting is with that

```
long
long
```

So when I execute the code, it ignores also the first node because they belong the same `ID='123'`, I think. This group with same `ID` can repeat N times. How can I select only the second `work` node's `description`, each repeated time with value of `"long"` by XPath, not based on text value.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do. Do you just need to create a node containing the text of each `work[2]/description/host` in each `node`? I.e. the second short description of each `node`?

Comment: Yeah exactly. I want to reach the second <short> node and say for each time you arrive that node do nothing otherwise do other things.

Comment: So you _do_ want to output something for each _first_ `<short>` node, but not for the second one? Can you show what result you would like to see for your sample input XML?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to process the **first** `description`
from each `node` with child `ID` = 123.

It leads to a conclusion, that you have **multiple** `node` elements,
so due to XML syntax requirements, they must be children of some parent
node (I assumed, they are direct children).

To get the required value, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::description[1]/short"/>
```

where `descendant::description[1]` gives just the first `description` element,
whatever its depth in the XML tree.

The whole script can be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="node[ID='123']">
        <description>
          <xsl:value-of select="descendant::description[1]/short"/>  
        </description>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5wi

I "expanded" your XML source, so it contains 2 `node` elements and my
script outputs first descriptions from each source `node`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already find the solution and will share here soon. Like I explained in the description, based on text such as ID='123' is not acceptable, because the text can change but the Xpath logic will be always the same no matter what the value is